# How can i programmatically click on ext menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can i programmatically click the ext menu checkitem? i have tried below code and it did change the checked. However, the checkbox didn't check. thank you.

```
extMenuCheckItem.items[0].checked = true;
```

And this doesn't work either.

```
extMenuCheckItem.items[0].onClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `extMenuCheckItem.items[0].click();` which simulates a click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your view:

```
 items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menu',
            floating: false,
            width: 120,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                    text: 'Menu Item'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                    text: 'Menu Item',
                    listeners: {
                        checkchange: 'onMenucheckitemCheckChange'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Controller to capture the action:

```
onMenucheckitemCheckChange: function(menucheckitem, checked, eOpts) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `extMenuCheckItem.items[0].set('checked', true)`

Answer (score 0):

with

```
extMenuCheckItem.items[0].onClick();
```

you just call one listener for the MenuItem.

But with

```
extMenuCheckItem.items[0].click();
```

you simulate the click on the MenuItem and the `click` event is fired, so every attached listener will run.